# How to generate a QR code for paypal payment?

Tags: javascript, php, html, paypal, qr-code

I have created a paypal button with official tool before:

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="paypal_form">

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" id="order_button_id" value="123123abc">
                        <input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="order_quantity">

<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Name">
                <input type="hidden" name="os0" value="" id="post_name">

                <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Email">
                <input type="hidden" name="os1" value="" id="post_email">

                <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Phone">
                <input type="hidden" name="os2" value="" id="post_tel">

<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/HK/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG_wCUP.gif" border="0" name="submit" style="position:relative; top:20px; left:20px;">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>
```

Recently, I need to convert this button to QR code, as I would like to allow my customer to scan the QR code at my shop, and make payment on their mobile phone.

To simplify, there is only one product and the quantity will always be one , How to convert that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please note, I have improved the code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new file like this:

```
<HTML><head><script>function SF(){document.getElementById('paypal_form').submit();}</script></head><body onload="SF();"><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="paypal_form"> <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"> <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" id="order_button_id" value="123123abc"> <input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="order_quantity"> <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Name"> <input type="hidden" name="os0" value="" id="post_name"> <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Email"> <input type="hidden" name="os1" value="" id="post_email"> <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Phone"> <input type="hidden" name="os2" value="" id="post_tel"> <input type="submit" value="Please click here if you are not redirected." border="0" style="position:relative; top:20px; left:20px;"> <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"> </form></body></HTML>
```

And make a QR code point to that.